Is a robust and OS agnostic function to download tar.gz archives from CRAN implemented somewhere?
I have done some searching but I can't find anything that will do the job "out-of-the-box". The majority of threads revolves around installing but I'm interested in downloading. I have written my own small utility (see below), but I'm interesed in something more OS agnostic, which is likely also more robust and does not require personal maintenance.
Have I overlooked something or does this simply not exists?
Function:
get_pack_tar_gz <- function(package, version, destination = ".") {
  package_tar_gz_string <- paste0(package, "_", version, ".tar.gz")
  latest_version_url <- paste0("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/",
                               package_tar_gz_string)
  archive_version_url <- paste0("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/",
                                package,
                                "/",
                                package_tar_gz_string)
  
  latest_return <- suppressWarnings(
    system(paste0("wget --spider ", latest_version_url, " 2> /dev/null"), intern = TRUE)
  )
  latest_return_status <- attributes(latest_return)$status
  
  if(length(latest_return_status) == 0) {
    system(paste0("wget -q https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/",
                  package_tar_gz_string,
                  " -P ",
                  destination))
  } else if(latest_return_status == 8) {
    system(paste0("wget -q https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/",
                  package,
                  "/",
                  package_tar_gz_string, 
                  " -P ",
                  destination))
  } else {
    stop("Unexpected!")
  }
  if(! file.exists(paste0(destination, "/", package_tar_gz_string))) {
    stop("No file retrieved!")
  }
}

Example calls:
get_pack_tar_gz(package = "tidyr", version = "1.3.1")
get_pack_tar_gz(package = "tidyr", version = "0.1")


There's an ex-exported function in remotes that grabs te URL with remotes:::download_version_url("tidyr", "0.1", getOption("repos"), "source") and then you can pass that to the base function download.file(). It's what devtools::install_version is doing behind the scenes.

For completeness, R also has the function download.packages() which works analogously to (and is used by) install.packages(). However, since it doesn’t allow specifying a version it doesn’t fit your concrete requirements.

Three more points: (1) I strongly urge using system2() instead of system(paste()) everywhere: it has a more consistent, less error-prone interface (though it’s still atrocious … the ‘processx’ package is vastly superior). (2) Always shQuote() command line arguments. This should be a hard and fast rule, regardless of what you think the command line arguments are. (3) R has the function download.file() which means that calling an external utility such as wget is unnecessary here anyway (at least for the download; there’s no equivalent of wget --spider that I am aware of).

Based on the comment from MrFlick we can rewrite a download call for several packages more concisely as follows:
# example data
packs_to_dl <- structure(list(name = c("fastmap", "r2r", "urca"),
                              version = c("1.1.0", "0.1.1", "1.3-3"),
                              out_file = c("fastmap_1.1.0.tar.gz",
                                           "r2r_0.1.1.tar.gz",
                                           "urca_1.3-3.tar.gz")),
                         row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L),
                         class = "data.frame")

# download
download.file(unlist(purrr::pmap(list(packs_to_dl$name,
                                      packs_to_dl$version,
                                      "https://cran.r-project.org",
                                      "source"),
                                 remotes:::download_version_url)),
              destfile = packs_to_dl$out_file)

